# rails don't calls the engine's controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to define some helper methods to be used in the app's controller, but it seems that rails don't even call the controller. just for the test I have the following controller in my `app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb` and as the documents say rails should find it first and an error should raise because `THIS_SHOULD_PRODUCE_ERROR` is unknown, but the `rspec` happily executing without any errors!

```
class ApplicationController <  ActionController::Base
  THIS_SHOULD_PRODUCE_ERROR
end
```

I even tried to mimic the [devise's way](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/test/rails_app/app/controllers/application_controller.rb) but the results are the same!

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @ashvin that is the problem, there is no error, which it means the rails didn't include the `app/controllers/my_engine/application_controller.rb` in the application!

Comment: Move your application controller to `app/controllers/application_controller` this path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [guide section on the app directory](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#app-directory) suggests that the `application_controller` in an engine "will provide any common functionality for the controllers *of the engine*".

So I wouldn't expect that any additions to that controller will be available to all controllers in an application.

That also means that your `application_controller` is, I suspect, not getting called when you're running your test. Which would explain why you're not seeing an error.

---

In terms of how devise does it I think you need to be looking at how [`define_helpers`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L110) works. The code you've linked to in your question is the application controller in the test app for the devise gem.

Comment: You are definitely correct, I couldn't figure out how devise does, but I have come up with a workaround and it works great, I guess :/ going to post it here for future wonders

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that I have got things wrong, and the `application_controller` in the engine does not get applied to `application_controller` in the app! Also,   I couldn't figure out how the devise did it, but I have come up with the simple workaround for this:

```
require_relative 'controllers/helpers'

module Acu
  module Injectors
    class << self

      ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe "start_processing.action_controller" do |**args|
        eval((Acu::Configs.get :base_controller).to_s).class_eval do
          include Acu::Controllers::Helpers
        end
      end

    end
  end
end
```

This will inject controller helpers to the user's base controller (which I get from the user, `default: :ApplicationController`) at the end of the class, which is perfect for me (but don't know how to add it to begging of the class if anyone needs it)